# Value of EditText (InputType: Date) to integer

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to get the value from EditText(InputType: Date) to integer.
Example: 10.01.2017 ==> 20170110

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
int inputDate = Integer.valueOf(df.format(etDate.getText().toString()));
```

How can i fix my problem?

thx and regards

Comment: That means, you are getting this - 10.01.2017 and want to convert to this - 20170110 ??

Comment: What's result of df.format(etDate.getText().toString()) ?? 10.01.2017 for example ???

Answer (score 1):

You can parse date. then form the `Date` object you can have `millies`

```
   DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    try {
        Date date=df.parse(textView.getText().toString());
        long millies=date.getTime();// Here is milli seconds
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Edit**

To convert one format to another . you can use .

```
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    DateFormat inputFormate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    try {
        Date date=inputFormate.parse(textView.getText().toString());
        String formated_date=df.format(date);
        // this will be formated_date
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Keep that in mind that use can input anything . So you need first check, in which format user entered date it can be `(dd/MM/yyyy)` or `(MM/dd/yyyy)`.

To get extra data from date or millies  use `Calender`.

```
 Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(millies);
    int day=calendar.get(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: This is what i got from your question . Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: My problem is to get date to integer.
The DB2 has a field dec 8,0 in which i must save.
In your code i get the millis to formated_date, or?

Comment: you can set millies to a `Calender` object and get each field value . See the updated answer .

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = editText.getText().toString();
String[] array = text.split("\\.");
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  stringBuilder.append(array[i]);
}
int date = Integer.parseInt(stringBuilder.toString());
```

I have this stupid way to help you.If you want want to accept this solution, maybe use Regular to solve it is better.